# My login form isn't working, it says variable was referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django

when I go to '/login', this error comes up:

UnboundLocalError at /login/
local variable 'form' referenced before assignment

[image: This is what it looks like]

This is my view:

```
from django import forms
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class LoginForm (forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField()

def login (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
#           username = request.POST['username']
#           password = request.POST['password']
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None and user.is_active:
                login(user)
                return redirect ("/login/success")
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    return render (request, 'login.html', {'form':form})
```

This is the template:

```
{% include 'base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<div class="videos">
<form method="post" class="bootstrap4">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form | crispy }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
Do't have an acount? Click <a href="/register">here</a> to create an account.
</div>
```

I don't see where it is referenced before assignment, and I get this error with python occasionlly, and I'm never able to figure out where it is referenced before assignment.

Comment: You only define `form` when someone posts to your login form. When it firsts loads its a get request so the `form` you are returning hasnt been defined

Comment: How do I fix that?

Comment: Have a `if request.method == 'GET` section or an `else` section and define the form in there

Comment: K. Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form only gets defined when there is a post request. In your if statement `if request.POST`, make sure to follow with an else statement telling what to return if the request is not `POST`.

Answer (score 1):

If `request.method` is not `POST` it goes directly to

```
return render (request, 'login.html', {'form':form})
```

and there the `form` is not assigned.

That happens when you go to the url because the method is `GET`. You need to add the `else` part.

```
def login (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None and user.is_active:
                login(user)
                return redirect ("/login/success")
    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    return render (request, 'login.html', {'form':form})
```